# What is a general scheme for writing a function in pointfree style?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, combinators, pointfree

I am working through the [20 Intermediate Haskell Exercises](http://blog.tmorris.net/20-intermediate-haskell-exercises/) at the moment, which is quite a fun exercise. It involves implementing various instances of the typeclasses `Functor` and `Monad` (and functions that takes `Functor`s and `Monad`s as arguments) but with cute names like `Furry` and `Misty` to disguise what we're doing (makes for some interesting code).

I've been trying to do some of this in a point-free style, and I wondered if there's a general scheme for turning a point-ful (?) definition into a point-free definition. For example, here is the typeclass for `Misty`:

```
class Misty m where
  unicorn :: a -> m a
  banana :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

(the functions `unicorn` and `banana` are `return` and `>>=`, in case it's not obvious) and here's my implementation of `apple` (equivalent to `flip ap`):

```
apple :: (Misty m) => m a -> m (a -> b) -> m b
apple x f = banana (\g -> banana (unicorn . g) x) f
```

Later parts of the exercises have you implement versions of `liftM`, `liftM2` etc. Here are my solutions:

```
appleTurnover :: (Misty m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
appleTurnover = flip apple

banana1 :: (Misty m) => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
banana1 =  appleTurnover . unicorn

banana2 :: (Misty m) => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
banana2 f = appleTurnover . banana1 f

banana3 :: (Misty m) => (a -> b -> c -> d) -> m a -> m b -> m c -> m d
banana3 f x = appleTurnover . banana2 f x

banana4 :: (Misty m) => (a -> b -> c -> d -> e) -> m a -> m b -> m c -> m d -> m e
banana4 f x y = appleTurnover . banana3 f x y
```

Now, `banana1` (equivalent to `liftM` or `fmap`) I was able to implement in pointfree style, by a suitable definition of `appleTurnover`. But with the other three functions I've had to use parameters.

My question is: **is there a recipe for turning definitions like these into point-free definitions**?

Comment: It's connected to the abstraction elimination you do to turn lambda calculus expressions into combinators. You might also want to check out the standalone [pointfree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) tool (also available as `@pl` in [lambdabot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lambdabot)).

Comment: [A related discussion I was having with a friend the other day](https://gist.github.com/1507246). You might find it interesting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As demonstrated by the `pointfree` utility, it's possible to do any such conversion automatically. However, the result is more often obfuscated than improved. If one's goal is to enhance legibility rather than destroy it, then the first goal should be to identify *why* an expression has a particular structure, find a suitable abstraction, and build things up that way.

The simplest structure is simply chaining things together in a linear pipeline, which is plain function composition. This gets us pretty far just on its own, but as you noticed it doesn't handle everything.

One generalization is to functions with additional arguments, which can be built up incrementally. Here's one example: Define `onResult = (. (.))`.  Now, applying `onResult` n times to an initial value of `id` gives you function composition with the result of an n-ary function. So we can define `comp2 = onResult (.)`, and then write `comp2 not (&&)` to define a NAND operation.

Another generalization--which encompasses the above, really--is to define operators that apply a function to a component of a larger value. An example here would be `first` and `second` in `Control.Arrow`, which work on 2-tuples. Conal Elliott's [Semantic Editor Combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators) are based on this approach.

A slightly different case is when you have a multi-argument function on some type `b`, and a function `a -> b`, and need to combine them into a multi-argument function using `a`. For the common case of 2-ary functions, the module `Data.Function` provides the `on` combinator, which you can use to write expressions like `` compare `on` fst `` to compare 2-tuples on their first elements.

It's a trickier issue when a single argument is used more than once, but there are meaningful recurring patterns here that can also be extracted. A common case here is applying multiple functions to a single argument, then collecting the results with another function. This happens to correspond to the `Applicative` instance for functions, which lets us write expressions like `(&&) <$> (> 3) <*> (< 9)` to check if a number falls in a given range.

The important thing, if you want to use any of this in actual code, is to think about what the expression *means* and how that's reflected in the structure. If you do that, and then refactor it into pointfree style using meaningful combinators, you'll often make the intent of the code *clearer* than it would otherwise be, unlike the typical output of `pointfree`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! One of the tricks is to write your dots in prefix notation rather than infix. Then you should be able to find new things that look like function composition. Here's an example:

```
banana2 f = appleTurnover . banana1 f
          = (.) appleTurnover (banana1 f)
          = ((.) appleTurnOver) . banana1 $ f
banana2 = (appleTurnover .) . banana1
```

The source code for the pointfree utility contains more, but this one handles a lot of cases.

```
banana4 f x y = appleTurnover . banana3 f x y
              = (.) appleTurnover ((banana3 f x) y)
              = ((.) appleTurnover) . (banana3 f x) $ y
banana4 f x = ((.) appleTurnover) . (banana3 f x)
            = (.) ((.) appleTurnover) (banana3 f x)
            = ((.) ((.) appleTurnover)) ((banana3 f) x)
            = ((.) ((.) appleTurnover)) . (banana3 f) $ x
banana4 f = ((.) ((.) appleTurnover)) . (banana3 f)
          = (.) ((.) ((.) appleTurnover)) (banana3 f)
          = ((.) ((.) ((.) appleTurnover))) (banana3 f)
          = ((.) ((.) ((.) appleTurnover))) . banana3 $ f
banana4 = ((.) ((.) ((.) appleTurnover))) . banana3
        = (((appleTurnover .) .) .) . banana3
```

Comment: This is also a good way to make your functions completely unreadable, of course...

Comment: Given `return` is called `unicorn` it seems the OP isn't worried about that =P.

Comment: @Claudiu: Well, that's coming from the exercises the OP is doing, which are basically deriving stuff like `Monad` from the ground up, using very silly names for the definitions.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following term rewrite system:

```
\x -> f x ------> f 
f y x ----------> flip f x y
\x -> f (g x) --> f . g
```

It is incomplete (read why in books about combinatory logic), but it's enough:

Here is banana2:

```
banana2 f = appleTurnover . banana1 f
```

Rewrite as a lambda:

```
banana2 = \f -> appleTurnover . banana1 f
```

Write (.) in prefix style:

```
banana2 = \f -> (.) appleTurnover (banana1 f)
```

Note that

```
banana2 = \f -> ((.) appleTurnover) (banana1 f)
```

So rule 3 can be applied. `f` is `(.) appleTurnover` and `g` is `banana`:

```
banana2 = ((.) appleTurnover) . banana1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `pointfree` package which takes a Haskell function definition and attempts to re-write it in a `pointfree` style. I'd suggest experimenting with it to get new ideas. See [this page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) for more details; the package is available [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree).

Answer (score 0):

Since pointfree style is combinators style, just apply known combinators definitions, reading them backwards to make the substitution:

```
B f g x = f (g x)     -- (.) , <$> for ((->) a)
C f x y = f y x       -- flip
K x y = x             -- const
I x = x               -- id
S f g x = f x (g x)   -- <*> , ap  for ((->) a)
W f x = f x x         -- join
(f >>= g) x = g (f x) x
(f =<< g) x = f (g x) x
```

At times `liftMx`, `liftAx`, `sequence`, `sequenceA` can simplify things. I'd also consider `foldr`, `unfoldr`, `iterate`, `until` etc. as basic combinators.

Often, using operator sections helps too:

```
op a b = (a `op` b) = (`op` b) a = (a `op`) b
```

Some patterns can become familiar and so, used directly:

```
((f .) . g) x y = f (g x y)
((. f) . g) x y = g x (f y)

(((f .) .) . g) x y z = (f .) (g x y) z = f (g x y z)
(((. f) .) . g) x y z = (. f) (g x y) z = g x y (f z)
```

etc.