# when to use and when not to use pointfree style in haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, pointfree

I just learned about pointfree style in Haskell and how it can help tidy up the code and make it easier to read. But sometimes they can make the code a bit too terse.

So, when I should I always use pointfree style and at what scenarios should I absolutely avoid pointfree style in Haskell?

Comment: It's a matter of taste and style which can be refined by reading and writing code. Also, this has been asked many times before.

Comment: No clear rule here. For what it's worth, I use simple common patterns like chains `f . g . h` but avoid "smart" stuff like `(.) . (. f) . g`. I sometimes abuse `f &&& g` and `f *** g`, and maybe some `curry/uncurry`, but I try to prevent myself to go too far in that realm. When in doubt, stick to pointful.

Comment: There are similar questions already asked and answered here (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681512/what-is-a-general-scheme-for-writing-a-function-in-pointfree-style?rq=1), but as written I think this one cannot be answered. It is too broad and opinion based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already commented, it's a matter of taste and there will always be edge cases where both styles are equally suited (or, indeed, a partially-pointed version is best). However, there are some cases where it's clear enough:

- If a pointed expression can be η-reduced just like that, it's usually a good idea to do it.

  ```
  f x = g (h x)
  ```

  should better be written

  ```
  f = g . h
  ```
- If you want to memoise some computation before accepting some function parameters, you must keep these parameters out of the scope. For instance,

  ```
  linRegression :: [(Double, Double)] -> Double -> Double
  linRegression ps x = a * x + b
   where a, b = -- expensive calculation of regression coefficients,
                -- depending on the `ps`
  ```

  isn't optimal performance-wise, because the coefficients will need to be recomputed for every `x` value received. If you make it point-free:

  ```
  linRegression :: [(Double, Double)] -> Double -> Double
  linRegression ps = (+b) . (a*)
   where a, b = ...
  ```

  this problem doesn't arise. (Perhaps GHC will in some cases figure this out by itself, but I wouldn't rely on it.)

  Often though, it is better to make it pointed nevertheless, just not with an `x` in the same scope as `a` and `b` but bound by a dedicated lambda:

  ```
  linRegression :: [(Double, Double)] -> Double -> Double
  linRegression ps = \x -> a * x + b
   where a, b = ...
  ```
- If the point-free version is actually *longer* than the pointed version, I wouldn't use it. If you need to introduce tricks to get it point-free like `flip` and the `Monad (a->)` instance and this doesn't even make it shorter, then it will almost certainly be less readable than the pointed version.

Comment: I think it's actually pretty hard to know what GHC will do, whether you write a manual lambda or not. In this case, I bet you'll get sharing either way, but the optimizer can add or remove sharing in somewhat hard-to-predict ways.

Comment: @dfeuer: are you sure? I'd be surprised if GHC ever _removed_ sharing, at least unless the shared expression inlines to a few opcodes that are clearly neglectable for performance.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. Roman Cheplyaka had some trouble with it doing so in a situation similar to this one in `regex-applicative` and had to disable some optimization to recover it.

Comment: That's troubling! In fact I'd lean to calling it a GHC bug.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite answer comes from Richard Bird's *Thinking Functionally with Haskell*: pointfree style helps you reason about function *composition* while a pointed style helps you reason about function *application*.

If you find that a pointfree style is awkward for writing a particular function then you generally have two options:

1. Use a pointed style instead. Sometimes you *do* want to reason about application.
2. Redesign your function to be compositional in nature.

In my own programs, I've found that (2) often leads to a better design and that this design can then be more clearly expressed using a pointfree style. Pointfree style is not an end goal: it is a means to achieving a more compositional design.