# Write f in pointfree-style?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

Say I have functions

```
g :: a -> b, h :: a -> c
```

and

```
f :: b -> c -> d.
```

Is it possible to write the function

```
 f' :: a -> a -> d
```

given by

```
f' x y = f (g x) (h y)
```

in point free style?.

One can write the function

```
f' a -> d, f' x = f (g x) (h x)
```

in point free style by setting

```
f' = (f <$> g) <*> h
```

but I couldn't figure out how to do the more general case.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We have:

```
k x y = (f (g x)) (h y)
```

and we wish to write `k` in point-free style.

The first argument passed to `k` is `x`. What do we need to do with `x`? Well, first we need to call `g` on it, and then `f`, and then do something fancy to apply this to `(h y)`.

```
k = fancy . f . g
```

What is this `fancy`? Well:

```
k x y = (fancy . f . g) x y
      = fancy (f (g x)) y
      = f (g x) (h y)
```

So we desire `fancy z y = z (h y)`. Eta-reducing, we get `fancy z = z . h`, or `fancy = (. h)`.

```
k = (. h) . f . g
```

---

A more natural way to think about it might be

```
                             ┌───┐           ┌───┐
                        x ───│ g │─── g x ───│   │
                      /      └───┘           │   │
               (x, y)                        │ f │─── f (g x) (h y)
                      \      ┌───┐           │   │
                        y ───│ h │─── h y ───│   │
                             └───┘           └───┘

                      └──────────────────────────────┘
                                      k
```

Enter [`Control.Arrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html):

```
k = curry ((g *** h) >>> uncurry f)
```

Comment: This is very different from the procedure I tend to follow myself. It's always refreshing to see a new way.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [online converter](https://blunt.herokuapp.com/#input=f%27%20x%20y%20%3D%20f%20(g%20x)%20(h%20y))

It converted

```
f' x y = f (g x) (h y)
```

into

```
f' = (. h) . f . g
```

with the flow of transformations

```
f' = id (fix (const (flip ((.) . f . g) h))) 
f' = fix (const (flip ((.) . f . g) h)) 
f' = fix (const ((. h) . f . g)) 
f' = (. h) . f . g
```

Comment: How did you/it go from `f' x y = f (g x) (h y)` to `f' = id (fix (const (flip ((.) . f . g) h)))`?

Comment: I am not expert in this. Looks like library has a set predefined transformations and performs search in the space of possible transformations. And by following simplifications looks like it has some redundant functions. For example first step could be `flip ((.) . f . g) h` without chain of `id(fix(const`

Answer (score 3):

This is slightly longer, but a little easier to follow, than `(. h) . f. g`.

First, rewrite `f'` slightly to take a tuple instead of two arguments. (In otherwords, we're uncurrying your original `f'`.)

```
f' (x, y) = f (g x) (h y)
```

You can pull a tuple apart with `fst` and `snd` instead of pattern matching on it:

```
f' t = f (g (fst t)) (h (snd t))
```

Using function composition, the above becomes

```
f' t = f ((g . fst) t) ((h . snd) t)
```

which, hey, looks a lot like the version you could make point-free using applicative style:

```
f' = let g' = g . fst
         h' = h . snd
     in (f <$> g') <*> h'
```

The only problem left is that `f' :: (a, a) -> d`. You can fix this by explicitly currying it:

```
f' :: a -> a -> d
f' = let g' = g . fst
         h' = h . snd
     in curry $ (f <$> g') <*> h'
```

(This is very similar, by the way, to the `Control.Arrow` solution added by Lynn.)

Comment: Easier to follow that `(. h) . f . g`? Er... I don't think so. Using the `Applicative (a->)` instance with tuples is giving you the _worst of both worlds_: cryptic dataflow semantics and awkward currying.

Comment: I find partial application of `(.)` to be even less understandable than `Applicative (a ->)`. The user already indicated an understanding (or at least awareness) of `Applicative`, so I built off that. The question was how to write a point-free version of the function; myself, I wouldn't bother and stick with the perfectly understandable `f x y = f (g x) (h y)`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the "three rules of operator sections" as applied to the `(.)` function composition operator,

```
(.) f g  =  (f . g)  =  (f .) g  =  (. g) f   -- the argument goes into the free slot
--       1           2           3
```

this is derivable by a few straightforward mechanical steps:

```
k x y =  (f (g x)) (h y)                      -- a (b c) === (a . b) c
      =  (f (g x) . h) y
      =  (. h)  (f (g x)) y
      =  (. h)  ((f . g)  x) y
      = ((. h) . (f . g)) x  y
```

Lastly, `(.)` is associative, so the inner parens may be dropped.

The general procedure is to strive to reach the situation where eta-reduction can be performed, i.e. we can get rid of the arguments if they are in same order and are outside any parentheses:

```
k x y = (......) y
=>
k x   = (......)
```

[Lather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681512/what-is-a-general-scheme-for-writing-a-function-in-pointfree-style/18174604#18174604), [rinse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169046/writing-in-pointfree-style-f-x-g-x-x/11050971#11050971), repeat.

---

Another trick  is to turn two arguments into one, or vice versa, with the equation

```
curry f x y = f (x,y)
```

so, your

```
f (g x) (h y) = (f.g) x (h y)                      -- by B-combinator rule
              = (f.g.fst) (x,y) ((h.snd) (x,y))
              = (f.g.fst <*> h.snd) (x,y)          -- by S-combinator rule
              = curry (f.g.fst <*> h.snd) x y
```

This is the same as the [answer by @chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38745362/849891), but presented more concisely.

So, you see, your `(f.g <*> h) x`<sup>1</sup> just becomes `(f.g.fst <*> h.snd) (x,y)`. Same difference.

---

<sup>1</sup>(because, for functions, `(<$>) = (.)`)

Answer (score 1):

[Control.Compose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.9.12)

```
(g ~> h ~> id) f
```

[Data.Function.Meld](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-function-meld)

```
f $* g $$ h *$ id
```

[Data.Function.Tacit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-function-tacit)

```
lurryA @N2 (f <$> (g <$> _1) <*> (h <$> _2))
lurryA @N5 (_1 <*> (_2 <*> _4) <*> (_3 <*> _5)) f g h
```

---

## Related articles

- [Semantic Editor Combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators), Conal Elliott, 2008/11/24
- [Pointless fun](http://matt.immute.net/content/pointless-fun), Matt Hellige, 2008/12/03