# Using foldr to define map (develop)

Tags: haskell, fold, currying

Having a hard time understanding fold... Is the expansion correct ? Also would appreciate any links, or analogies that would make fold more digestible.

```
foldMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
foldMap f [] = []
foldMap f xs = foldr (\x ys -> (f x) : ys) [] xs


b =  (\x ys -> (f x):ys)
foldMap (*2) [1,2,3]
= b 1 (b 2 (foldr b [] 3))
= b 1 (b 2 (b 3 ( b [] [])))
= b 1 (b 2 ((*2 3) : []))
= b 1 ((*2 2) : (6 :[]))
= (* 2 1) : (4 : (6 : []))
= 2 : (4 : (6 : []))
```

Comment: The implementation is correct, although you can remove the first clause. In essence you can see `foldr f z` as something that replaces the `(:)` of the list with `f`, and the `[]` with `z`.

Comment: the last line of your example is wrong. According to the function above, it should be `foldr (\x ys -> (2*x) : ys) [] [1, 2, 3, 4]`. And then you can expand that recursively using the definition of `foldr`.

Comment: your first definition is for `map`, not `foldMap`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond ah yes i got it now

Comment: @WillNess ah youre right

Answer (score 6):

First, let's not use the name `foldMap` since that's already [a standard function different from `map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap). If you want to re-implement an existing function with the same or similar semantics, convention is to give it *the same name* but either in a separate module, or with a prime `'` appended to the name. Also, we can omit the empty-list case, since you can just pass that to the fold just as well:

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map' f xs = foldr (\x ys -> f x : ys) [] xs
```

Now if you want to evaluate this function by hand, first just use the definition without inserting anything more:

```
map' (*2) [1,2,3,4]
 ≡ let f = (*2)
       xs = [1,2,3,4]
   in foldr (\x ys -> (f x) : ys) [] xs
 ≡ foldr (\x ys -> (*2) x : ys) [] [1,2,3,4]
```

Now just prettify a bit:

```
 ≡ foldr (\x ys -> x*2 : ys) [] [1,2,3,4]
```

Now to evaluate this through, you also need the definition of [`foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr). It's actually a bit different in GHC, but effectively

```
foldr _ z []     =  z
foldr f z (x:xs) =  f x (foldr f z xs)
```

So with your example

```
  ...
 ≡ foldr (\x ys -> x*2 : ys) [] (1:[2,3,4])
 ≡ (\x ys -> x*2 : ys) 1 (foldr (\x ys -> x*2 : ys) [] [2,3,4])
```

Now we can perform a β-reduction:

```
 ≡ 1*2 : foldr (\x ys -> x*2 : ys) [] [2,3,4]
 ≡ 2 : foldr (\x ys -> x*2 : ys) [] [2,3,4]
```

...and repeat for the recursion.

Answer (score 5):

`foldr` defines a family of equations,

```
foldr g n [] = n
foldr g n [x] = g x (foldr g n []) = g x n
foldr g n [x,y] = g x (foldr g n [y]) = g x (g y n)
foldr g n [x,y,z] = g x (foldr g n [y,z]) = g x (g y (g z n))
                        ----- r ---------
```

and so on. `g` is a *reducer* function,

```
                    g x r = ....
```

accepting as `x` an element of the input list, and as `r` the *r*esult of *r*ecursively processing the *r*est of the input list (as can be seen in the equations).

`map`, on the other hand, defines a family of equations

```
map f [] = []
map f [x] = [f x] = (:) (f x) [] = ((:) . f) x []
map f [x,y] = [f x, f y] = ((:) . f) x (((:) . f) y [])
map f [x,y,z] = [f x, f y, f z] = ((:) . f) x (((:) . f) y (((:) . f) z []))
                                =  (:)  (f x) ( (:)  (f y) ( (:)  (f z) []))
```

The two families simply exactly match with

```
g = ((:) . f) = (\x -> (:) (f x)) = (\x r -> f x : r)
```

and `n = []`, and thus

```
foldr ((:) . f) [] xs  ==  map f xs
```

---

We can prove this rigorously by mathematical induction on the input list's length, following the defining laws of `foldr`,

```
foldr g n [] = []
foldr g n (x:xs) = g x (foldr g n xs)
```

which are the basis for the equations at the top of this post.

Modern Haskell has `Fodable` type class with its basic `fold` following the laws of

```
fold(<>,n) [] = n
fold(<>,n) (xs ++ ys) = fold(<>,n) xs <> fold(<>,n) ys
```

and the `map` is naturally defined in its terms as

```
map f xs  =  foldMap (\x -> [f x]) xs
```

turning `[x, y, z, ...]` into `[f x] ++ [f y] ++ [f z] ++ ...`, since for lists `(<>) == (++)`. This follows from the equivalence

```
    f x : ys  ==  [f x] ++ ys
```

This also lets us define `filter` along the same lines easily, as

```
filter p xs  =  foldMap (\x -> [x | p x]) xs
```

---

To your specific question, the expansion is correct, except that  `(*2 x)` should be written as `((*2) x)`, which is the same as `(x * 2)`. `(* 2 x)` is not a valid Haskell (though valid Lisp :) ).

Functions like `(*2)` are known as "[operator sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743576/write-f-in-pointfree-style/38749169#38749169)" -- the missing argument goes into the empty slot: `(* 2) 3 = (3 * 2) = (3 *) 2 = (*) 3 2`.

You also asked for some links: see e.g. [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold#List_folds_as_structural_transformations), [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lists_III) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#As_structural_transformations).