# How to use foldr to add variables to each other in a list?

Tags: list, function, haskell, fold, map-function

When given a list `[x0, x1, x2, . . . , xn−1]`, the function
should return the list `[y0, y1, y2, . . . , yn−1]` where `y0 = x0, y1 = x0 + x1, ...`

So if you had `[1,2,3]` as input, you would get `[1,3,6]` as output

I don't completely understand `foldr`, so maybe if I could get some help in trying to figure out how to change that last line to get the right answer.

```
scan :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
scan [] = []
scan [x] = [x]

scan (x:xs) = x : foldr (/y -> y (+) x) 0 (scan xs)
```

My initial solution (that works) uses the `map` function.

```
scan :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
scan [] = []
scan [x] = [x]

scan (x:xs) = x : map (+x) (scan xs)
```

Comment: Why do you want to ıuse `foldr`..? This functionality already exists. `Data.List.scanl1` is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**, I added this first section to better address your two implementations.

First, addressing your issue with your implementation using `foldr`, here are a few remarks:

1. Lambdas start with a backslash in Haskell, not a slash. That's because backslashes kind of look like the lambda greek letter (λ).
2. Functions named using only special characters, like `+`, are infix by default. If you use parens around them, it turns them into prefix functions:

```
$> (+) 1 5
$> 6
```

3. The function passed to `foldr` takes two argument, whereas you're only supplying one in your lambda. If you really want to ignore the second one, you can use a `_` instead of binding it to a variable (`\x _ -> x`).

I think this you're going down a rabbit hole with this implementation. See the discussion below for my take on the right way to tackle this issue.

*Note*: It is possible to implement `map` using `foldr` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495472/using-foldr-to-define-map-develop)), that's one way you could use `foldr` in your working (second) implementation.

---

Implementing this with `foldr` is not optimal, since it folds, as the name implies, from the right:

```
foldr1 (+) [1..5]
--is equivalent to:
(1+(2+(3+(4+5))))
```

As you can see, the summing operation is done starting from the tail of the list, which is not what you're looking for. To make this work, you would have to "cheat", and reverse your list twice, once before folding it and once after:

```
scan = tail . reverse . foldr step [0] . reverse where
  step e acc@(a:_) = (e + a) : acc
```

You can make this better using a left fold, which folds from the left:

```
foldl1 (+) [1..5]
--is equivalent to:
((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)
```

This, however, still isn't ideal, because to keep the order of elements in your accumulator the same, you would have to use the `++` function, which amounts to quadratic time complexity in such a function. A compromise is to use the `:` function, but then you still have to reverse your accumulator list after the fold, which is only linear complexity:

```
scan' :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
scan' = tail . reverse . foldl step [0] where
  step acc@(a:_) e = (e + a) : acc
```

This still isn't very good, since the `reverse` adds an extra computation. The ideal solution would therefore be to use `scanl1`, which, as a bonus, doesn't require you to give a starting value (`[0]` in the examples above):

```
scan'' :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
scan'' = scanl1 (+)
```

[`scanl1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#scanl1) is implemented in terms of `scanl`, which is defined roughly like this:

```
scanl f init list = init : (case list of
                      []   -> []
                      x:xs -> scanl f (f init x) xs)
```

You can therefore simply do:

```
$> scanl1 (+) [1..3]
$> [1,3,6]
```

As a final note, your `scan` function is unnecessarily specialized to `Integer`, as it only requires a `Num` constraint:

```
scan :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
```

This might even lead to an increase in performance, but that's where my abilities end, so I won't go any further :)

Comment: in case you haven't seen this kind of thing, 1. `scanl f a xs = ys where { ys = a : zipWith f ys xs = a : map (uncurry f) (zip ys xs) }`. 2. `scanl f a xs = foldr g z xs a where { z a = [a] ; g x r a = a : r (f a x) }`. :)

Comment: @WillNess Hmm.. I'm sure those snippets are very clever, but they don't compile...

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer! What you're saying makes complete sense. I know I didn't mention it, but I was looking for a solution that specifically used recursion because thats the problem I'm trying to answer requires that (very new to Haskell, so just trying to learn all the fundamentals). Also the reason I was trying to use foldr/foldl was to just understand how those functions worked in a practical scenario. Any advice on where I would need to actually use them?

Comment: @Biggeez `foldr`, `foldl`, and `scanl` all use recursion. Since recursion is a very common pattern in functional programming, it's usually abstracted away into higher-order functions. If you want to use explicit recursion, you're basically reimplementing those functions, so it's a good idea to take a look at how they work. You can find tons of examples using folds, just search for `[haskell] fold` on SO, or take a look at [`Foldr Foldl Foldl'`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27) on the Haskell Wiki.

Comment: Just wanted to share something nice. :) the second works as is, the first contains two definitions, each works, separately. see also https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr, https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr_alternative. "`r`" is mnemonic for "Recursively calculated Result for the Rest of input". (and since we apply it to further argument, it's a function (in the 2.)) ((also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235148/implement-zip-using-foldr/26285107#26285107))

Comment: the point to the rewrite of `zipWith` as `map ... zip ...` was to show that `zipWith` is just a binary `map`. in fact in e.g. Scheme `map` accepts any number of arguments as long as their number matches the combining function's arity.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for sharing. I did not notice about `zipWith`!